# symmetric FFT in matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft, symmetric

I'm going to implement OFDM system in matlab. I need to take IFFT symmetric from data and then again FFT from results. the IFFT goes right, but the FFT doesn't, fisrt half of result numbers are like data bef0r IFFT, but second half is wrong. I just don't know should I use FFT function when I know the IFFT took 'symmetric'.

here is the functions I used:

```
x_ifft=ifft(x1, 'symmetric')    
x_fft=fft(x_ifft);
```

Thank you

Comment: @Jigg Yes, numbers are complex in freq domain, I need symmetric IFFT and then FFT.

Comment: Have you looked at `fftshift`? Using this function might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use "symmetric", but should use fftshift either after ifft or after fft.